# Value of allegedly infinite limit is different for different values of the variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, parametric-functions

I have a $5$-variables function $f(x,y,z,u,v)$ and I want to compute the limit as $x\to\frac{3\pi}u$; using this code for general values of parameters, Mathematica gives the answer `DirectedInfinity[Csc[(3 π z)/u]]`

```
f := 2 x Csc[x z] Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[x z] + (v Sin[x z])/( 2 x) + (Cos[u x] - Cos[y]) Csc[u x] Sin[x z])^2]

Limit[f, x -> 3 π/u ] // 
 Simplify[#, Assumptions -> u > 0 && u ∈ Reals && v ∈ Reals && z > 0 &&  z ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals] &
(* DirectedInfinity[Csc[(3 π z)/u]] *)
```

Ex1. For particular values of parameters $z=1,\, u=3,\,v=2,\,y=0$, it gives `Indeterminate`

```
z := 1; u := 3; v := 2; y := 0;

Limit[f, x -> 3 π/u ] // 
 Simplify[#, Assumptions -> u > 0 && u ∈ Reals && v ∈ Reals && z > 0 &&  z ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals] &
(* Indeterminate *)
```

Ex2. For other values of parameters $z=11,\, u=2,\,v=-2,\,y=\pi$, it gives `I Sqrt[-4 + 9 π^2]`

```
z := 11; u := 2; v := -2; y := π;

Limit[f, x -> 3 π/u ] // 
 Simplify[#, Assumptions -> u > 0 && u ∈ Reals && v ∈ Reals && z > 0 &&  z ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals] &
(* I Sqrt[-4 + 9 π^2]*)
```

**My Questions:**

> Can someone please explain why the results are different for a different set of values of the variables involved? In particular, if the result is `DirectedInfinity[Csc[(3 π z)/u]]` for general parameters, then why is the result of Ex2 not infinity?

> Is `DirectedInfinity[Csc[(3 π z)/u]]` a determinate or indeterminate form?

Comment: The `Indeterminate` makes sense; $\csc(3\pi/3)$ is not a number.  The `I Sqrt[9π^2-4]` is confusing since $\csc(33\pi/2)=1$.  I can't find a good definition for 'converging/diverging to `DirectedInfinity@θ`' at $\vec x_0$, but we'll say that it means for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so that $|\theta-\arctan f(\vec x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $\vec x$ with $|\vec x_0-\vec x|<\delta$.  Maybe we should add also that $|f(\vec x)|>\frac1\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Adam Thanks. Can I trust the first general result and conclude that the function always tends to infinity at that limit?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau The whole question is here.

Comment: (1) To have a note sent you need to consolidate the full name with no space, so in my case it would be "@DanielLichtblau"

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for pointing out this :)

Comment: (2) Small perturbations of the parameters followed by taking the limit seem to give infinities. Guessing this is a situation where substituting integers can give isolated non-infinite results.

Comment: Actually, just perturbing `y` a bit away from `Pi` gives `Infinity` (and I received that last note by the way).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau So, is this a bug? since the first code and its answer misleads me that the limit is always infinity.

Comment: Truth is I don't know if it is a bug or a feature. If the set of incorrect points is discrete or at least measure zero with respect to the assumptions then it is regarded as not a bug. The small set of checks I did lead me to believe that might be the case. But I did not check in any way I consider as exhaustive.

Comment: I checked some more. It's not a bug. I'll post the relevant analysis.

Comment: `DirectedInfinity` is not a math notion, but an invention of Mathematica developers.

Comment: @user64494 Actually the notion of directed infinity, [shown here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-64/issue-2/Plus-and-times/pjm/1102867089.pdf),  predates Mathematica development. And it's a mathematical notion regardless of origin.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If I want to report the result of this limit in a scientific project, what notion I should use which is mathematically acceptable?

Comment: @user64494 If I want to report the result of this limit in a scientific project, what notion I should use which is mathematically acceptable?

Comment: Really depends on the needs/requirements/protocols of the project. Perhaps it could be claimed as "infinite almost everywhere with respect to the parameters". That's something mathematicians should understand but I do not know if that's the intended audience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result given is generically correct. Here is the analysis.

```
ff = 2 x Csc[x z] Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[x z] +
 (v Sin[x z])/(2 x) +
 (Cos[u x] - Cos[y]) Csc[u x] Sin[x z])^2];
```

We'll take a Laurent series up to order zero.

```
nn = Normal[Series[ff, {x, 3*Pi/u, 0}, 
   Assumptions -> u > 0 && v \[Element] Reals &&
  z > 0 && y \[Element] Reals]]

(* Out[278]= -((
  6 \[Pi] Sqrt[
   1/(3 \[Pi] - u x)^2] (3 \[Pi] - u x) Abs[
    Sin[(3 \[Pi] z)/u]] (1 + Cos[y]) Csc[(3 \[Pi] z)/u])/(
  u^2 (-((3 \[Pi])/u) + x))) - (
 Sqrt[1/(3 \[Pi] - u x)^2] (3 \[Pi] - u x) Abs[
   Sin[(3 \[Pi] z)/u]] (2 + u v + 2 Cos[y] + 
    6 \[Pi] Cot[(3 \[Pi] z)/u]) Csc[(3 \[Pi] z)/u])/u *)
```

Now we do a check that this is a decent series approximation, by showing some random numeric substitutions give a quotient near unity.

```
Flatten[Table[{nn/ff} /. 
   With[{uval = RandomReal[]},
  {y -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
     z -> RandomReal[],
     v -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
     y -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}], u -> uval, 
     x -> 3*Pi/uval +
       1/100*RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}], {10}]]

(* Out[283]= {1., 1.00002, 1.00009, 1., 1.,
  1.00001, 1.00467, 1., 1., 1.00011} *)
```

Now we look at the lead term, which is a pole.

```
In[285]:= nn2 = Normal[
  Series[ff, {x, 3*Pi/u, -1}, 
   Assumptions -> 
    u > 0 && v \[Element] Reals &&
    z > 0 && y \[Element] Reals]]

(* Out[285]= -((6 \[Pi]
  Sqrt[1/(3 \[Pi] - u x)^2] (3 \[Pi] - u x)
  Abs[Sin[(3 \[Pi] z)/u]] (1 + Cos[y]) 
  Csc[(3 \[Pi] z)/u])/
  (u^2 (-((3 \[Pi])/u) + x))) *)
```

There is a differential constant that adjusts for location of the expansion variable `x` with respect to `3*Pi/u`; this is required because we expand at a branch point. And there is a first order pole at `x=3*Pi/u`. But this goes away if you substitute `y->Pi` then this entire term evaporates.

```
nn2 /. y -> Pi

(* Out[291]= 0 *)
```

Other special substitutions can likewise cause the behavior to change. So the limit is generically correct but not correct for some specialized values of the parameters.